# Probability: What is the difference between $E[X|Y]$ versus $E[X|y]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation

Given two random variables $X,Y$ is there any difference between $E[X|Y]$ versus $E[X|y]$?

---

For the longest time I thought this was a notation preference between different authors.

But someone alerted me that $E[X|Y]$ maybe seen as a generalized version of $E[X|y]$

I am not quite sure what this means.

---

For example, given $f_{XY}(x,y) = 1, 0 < |y|<x<1; = 0$ everywhere else, it can be shown that $$E[X|Y]  = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x|y) dx = \dfrac{1+|y|}{2}, -1< y<1$$

(We used the fact $f_Y(y) = 1 - |y|, -1 < y < 1$)

**Would there be any difference if we evaluated $E[X|y]$ instead?**

**Addendum:** p. 231 Papoulis 4th edition

[image]

Comment: Any reference using the notation $E(X\mid y)$? Likewise, the conclusion of your example should read $$E(X\mid Y)=\tfrac12(1+|Y|)$$

Comment: @Did Yes, the author typically separates out bold and unbold with diligence

Comment: However, (6.233) is faulty since the LHS should read $$E(\mathbf x\mid\mathbf y=y)$$ instead of $$E(\mathbf x\mid\mathbf y)$$ That, or every $y$ in the RHS should read $\mathbf y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable, hence by the [Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma) there is a Borel function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=g(Y)$. We then write $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ for $g(y)$. Note that $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ is a random variable, while $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ is a real number.

Comment: I don't quite understand. It seems to be that both $E[X|Y]$ and $E[X| Y = y]$ are given by the same integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x f_X(x|y)dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x \dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx$

Comment: That integral is computing $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ for a given $y$.

Comment: Here is perhaps a simpler example to give you an idea of the distinction between the two: if $X$ and $Z$ are independent $U([0,1])$ random variables and $Y=X+Z$, then $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]=\frac{y}{2}$ for $0\leq y\leq 2$, while $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=\frac{Y}{2}$.

Comment: Hi, I have attached a reference to my example

Comment: Your book is using somewhat non-standard notation. What it has computed is $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$.

Comment: Ok. But it also uses $\mathbb{E}[X|y]$ lower case, e.g., eq. 6.236

Comment: Maybe it's just a bad book. Think about it this way: $g(y)=\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ is a real-valued function of the real number $y$. $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]=g(Y)$ is the corresponding random variable.